# Get record with min time difference

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have an requirement where I need to get a record with min time difference with current record.
Let us assume that in a table I have insert date, group Id and Id column.
I have selected a record and not want to get another record for which difference between insert date of selected record and another record is min.

I have tried outer apply, but that query takes forever to run.

Query:

```
select e.id
from B.Emp t
where id = 5
outer apply (
    select top 1 *
    from B.Emp 
    where t.group_id = group_id 
    order by insert_time desc ) e
```

Comment: can u share some sample data?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you indeed want to find closest insert time for the selected record' group, regardless of the direction, then something like this might help:

```
select t.insert_date, ca.*
from B.Emp t
    outer apply (
        select top (1) * from B.Emp e
        where e.group_id = t.group_id
            and e.id != t.id
        order by abs(datediff(ms, t.insert_date, e.insert_date))
    ) ca
where t.Id = 5;
```

**EDIT:** You will definitely need to check indexing options, though. For starters, assuming you have a clustered primary key on `Id` column, this should help:

```
create index [IX_B_Emp_GroupInsert] on B.Emp (group_id, insert_time);
```

Comment: This is what I tried, but table has millions of record, so query is running forever without producing a result.

Comment: @vinodsahu, have you looked into execution plan? What indices are recommended for the table? As a wild guess, I would probably start with something like `(group_id, insert_date)`.

Comment: I am not an sql expert, But one of my teammate did try with index, in execution plan it shows that outer apply is going to check all record

Answer (score 1):

```
select * From B.Emp emp
Inner Join 
(
    select MAX(emp1.insert_time) maxTime, emp1.id From B.Emp emp1 group by emp1.id
) maxDateRec ON maxDateRec.id = emp.id AND maxDateRec.maxTime = emp.insert_time
where emp.id = 5
```

Try with this second one.

Comment: I tried this, but result shows all record of that group id including id  5

Comment: let me see the issue.

Answer (score 0):

This Query is not tested.
Please reply me is any error or changes needs to be done in the query.

```
CREATE TABLE Emp
(   
    group_Id INT,
    ID INT,
    date DATETIME
)

INSERT INTO EMP
(group_Id,ID,date)
values
(1,5,'11-Jan-2014'),
(1,5,'12-Jan-2014')
```

--

```
select ID,date from Emp t
group by
ID,
date having id = 5
and 
date  =
(select max(date) from Emp where id = 5)
```

Comment: @Multisync I just tried to give the idea. I hope this will work